# I have four or five arrays of objects and want to filter in a way, I can get same objects in a new array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider I have this Unordered List and hidden List Items inside it. {[on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/concypt/btk7r/)}

```
<ul>
<li class="brand pro size color">one</li>
<li class="brand pro color">two</li>
<li class="brand pro size color">three</li>
<li class="pro size color">four</li>
<li class="brand pro size color">five</li>
<li class="pro color">six</li>
<li class="brand pro size color">seven</li>
<li class="brand pro size color">eight</li>
<li class="brand size color">nine</li>
<li class="brand pro color">ten</li>
</ul>
```

I have four arrays:

```
    var myBrand = $("ul li.brand");
var myPro = $("ul li.pro");
var mySize = $("ul li.size");
var myColor = $("ul li.color");
```

I want to have "same objects" in a new array called mySelected.

I have done this for two arrays like this:

```
var mySelected = myBrand.filter(function() {
return $.inArray(this, myPro) > -1;
});
mySelected.show();
```

I am wondering how to do it for "four" or more arrays?

Comment: Don't compare jQuery object directly, because everytime you call selector/traversal function you get new jQuery object. See - http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide27 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to loop through them. With EcmaScript 5's `every` you can:

```
var mySelected = myBrand.filter(function() {
    var li = this;
    return [myPro, mySize, myColor].every( function(array) {
        return $.inArray(li, array) > -1;
    });
});
```

EDIT: According to [jQuery's api](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), the filter method also takes jQuery sets as an argument. So the follwing should be working, too:

```
var mySelected = myBrand;
var setsToBeMatched = [myPro, mySize, myColor];
for (var i=0; i<setsToBeMatched.length; i++)
    mySelected = mySelected.filter(setsToBeMatched[i]);
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems its not working please see this http://jsfiddle.net/concypt/btk7r/

Comment: @Imran - what browser are you using?  Older ones might not support this function.

Comment: Sorry, needed a quick fix. The second function requires not to use this. I've updated your fiddle, should be working now.

Comment: what browsers do not support ECMAScript5?

Comment: IE6, IE7 and IE8 do not support "every" is there any alternative to this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Compatibility

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all the `<li>` elements that have all four classes then you can just use a selector and select them at once:

```
var mySelected = $('ul li.brand.pro.size.color');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/btk7r/1/

**UPDATE**

If you have an array of classes this can be made more dynamic:

```
var class_arr  = ['brand', 'pro', 'size', 'color', 'length', 'width'],
    mySelected = $('ul li.' + class_arr.join('.'));
```

Comment: no above is just an example to explain but it is not that simple

Comment: @Imran Well please describe what's different would be a good idea. Your question asks for a jQuery object with all the `<li>` items that have each class. You can concoct a string of classes to do this dynamically: `var mySelected = $('ul li.' + class_arr.join('.'));`

Comment: I don't have classes like I show in example... I am looking some other approach. Above example is just an simple example not exact. I have different objects getting after some manipulation.

Comment: @Imran OK I guess the point of my answer was to show that if you are making several different selections with jQuery selectors then you can make the intersection of those selections with a single jQuery selection. **Also** if you're posting a problem, why not post the actual problem so actual solutions can be posted as answers?

Comment: I am modifying a plugin. I don't have selectors as you mentioned above. I have done for two arrays you can see it here:http://jsfiddle.net/concypt/3cYNt/2/